# git clone gives error 404

Tags: git

from sourceforge.net when try when type git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/mutillidae/git mutillidae-git inside metasploitable -2 i get this message

error: Unable to get pack index http://git.code.sf.net/p/mutillidae/git/objects/pack/pack-3f124f0db19793f8534bbcabdf225ce1e24112.idx

The requested URL returned error:404

how to fix this ?

this is regarding metasploitable -2 while updating mutillidae a vulnerable web app.

Regards
skorpinok

Comment: The command clones a new tree.  It works fine if you do it in its own directory.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me over `git://`:

```
$ git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/mutillidae/git mutillidae-git
Cloning into 'mutillidae-git'...
remote: Counting objects: 4844, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3614/3614), done.
remote: Total 4844 (delta 1313), reused 4403 (delta 933)
Receiving objects: 100% (4844/4844), 11.62 MiB | 1.13 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1313/1313), done.
Checking connectivity... done
```

Comment: now its cloned without error, but i made a mistake by renaming original folder to mutillidae.bak, now when i try to access from other vm's through local host its not found so where this is cloned ? am i missing something ?

Comment: @user2715789 No idea; that isn't related to your question.